# unable to read unknown load command 0x25

Tags: load, command, xib

iPad Development: works fine in simulator, get memory warning on device. Using the 'release' function on everything. Getting this error:

unable to read unknown load command 0x25

unable to read unknown load command 0x26

It crashes after just a few xib changes. Help!

Answer (score 2):

```
#define LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS 0x25

struct version_min_command {
uint32_t    cmd;        /* LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX or
                   LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS  */
    uint32_t    cmdsize;    /* sizeof(struct min_version_command) */
    uint32_t    version;    /* X.Y.Z is encoded in nibbles xxxx.yy.zz */
    uint32_t    sdk;        /* X.Y.Z is encoded in nibbles xxxx.yy.zz */
```